# listview and screen orientation

Tags: android, listview, landscape, listadapter

I dont' event know if it's possible but here is what I would like to achieve. I have some actvities that show some data in listviews with list adapters (just compòsed of text views).

The layout is based on:

And Here is the basic composition of one "row" of the listView:
textview1
textView2
textView4
textview5
inflatedview

(+++headers and footers)

So there is one column which looks fine when device is in portrait orientation but when in landscape there is a lot of space at the right of the screen plus you need tyo scroll a lot.

Well what I would like is that in landscape, two columns of the same list are shown. ( And later maybe for tablets 3 columns but that is for later....)

ok I know I could do:

textview textView

textView textView

but I don't want that

How could I implement that? I mean which tools to use?

thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this we have one event is there when mobile orientation is changed i,e;

```
((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation()
```

By using above code we get the screen orientation .If orienation is landscape at that time you take 2 listviews side by side ,and set the values to that listviews

Comment: thank you I have the idea now! but the only thing is I don't know how many elements there will be in the list (this value changes cos the data is charged from elsewhere) how to do that part of the data is shown in left and other in the right? forst left, second right...???

Comment: You can also use `getRequestedOrientation()` to get the Current Activity Orientation.

Comment: For getRequestedOrientation() I need to have specified an orientation like a prefered screen orientation but I didn't and don't want to.

Comment: For getOrientation() it is deprecated hope the won't be any problems to use it because it's great I have tested it with emulator and returns 0 for portrait and 1 for landscape!!!